# How to make a single <td> element in a <tr> not sortable (jquery ui)

Tags: html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a table like this

```
<table>
  <tr class="sortable">
    <td>Days</td>
    <td>Monday</td>
    <td>Tuesday</td>
    <td>Wednesday</td>
    <td>Thursday</td>
    <td>Friday</td>
    <td>Saturday</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="sortable">
    <td>Works</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

In this, I don't want the `<td>`'s "Days" and "Works" not sort-able but remaining in the row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the row headers `<th>` as they should be and include only `<td>` elements.

```
<table>
  <tr class="sortable">
    <th>Days</th>
    <td>Monday</td>
     ...

​$( '​​​​.sortable' ).sortable({
    items: 'td'
});​​​​​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Xugru/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `cancel` option for this:

```
$('.sortable').sortable({
    cancel: 'td:first'
});
```

Here's [docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-cancel).

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
  <tr class="sortable">
    <td>Days</td>
    <td>Monday</td>
    <td>Tuesday</td>
    <td>Wednesday</td>
    <td>Thursday</td>
    <td>Friday</td>
    <td>Saturday</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="sortable">
    <td>Works</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

***Let's make the column id not to be sortable.***

```
$(".sortable").sortable({
 items: "td:not(:first)"
});
```

That's all. All you need is to excludethe first td in items.

Have a great day