# Sortable: disable a column in a sortable row

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I've a html table with 4 columns and few rows. The rows need to be sortable (I am using jquery ui sortable), however the outer left
td should never move. So basically I'd like to be able to move the row without moving the outer left td in that row.
I've tried to mess around with items option and cancel method with no success.
I looked up similar threads but my aim is not to make every td sortable:

[jquery sortable with multiple tbody](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16151800/jquery-sortable-with-multiple-tbody)

[How to make a single <td> element in a <tr> not sortable (jquery ui)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14069435/how-to-make-a-single-td-element-in-a-tr-not-sortable-jquery-ui)

Is this doable using sortable?
If someone could point me in the right direction I would appreciate it a lot.

My mark up:

```
<table>
    <tr class="head_row">
    <td>Counter</td>
        <td>Position</td>
        <td>Note</td>
        <td>Visible</td>
    </tr>
    <tbody class="sort">
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>TEST1</td>
            <td>Y</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>TEST2</td>
            <td>Y</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>TEST3</td>
            <td>Y</td>
   </tr>

   </tbody>
```

jquery:

```
$(function(){
    $(".sort").sortable({
        helper: fixWidth,
        revert : true,
        cursor: "move",
        opacity: 0.5
    });
});


// fixes the width of the table rows while sorting
    var fixWidth = function(e, tr) {
        var $originals = tr.children();
        var $helper = tr.clone();
        $helper.children().each(function(index)
        {
          $(this).width($originals.eq(index).width())
        });
        return $helper;
    };
```

Here's a link to what I have so far:

`http://jsfiddle.net/zSzks/2/`

The "counter" column shouldn't move in this case.

Thank you,
Monika

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach - really not the smartest - could be to seperate the Counter section into another table.
It looks the same and works like you want it to work but as I said I think it's just not the smartest way to solve your issue.

Anyway see what I did: <kbd>[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/SirDerpington/zSzks/3/)</kbd>

**HTML**

```
<table id="counterTable">
    <thead>
        <tr class="head_row">
            <th>Counter</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="fake">
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
#counterTable {
    float: left;
    /* to hide the noticeable difference between the 2 tables */
    margin-right: -2px;
}
.sort td, .fake td {
    border: 1px solid;
    width: 100px;
}
```

By the way you should usually wrap your table headings in `<th>` tags so your titles (like Counter, Position, Note, ...) are recognizable as headings.

**EDIT (SOLUTION)**

<kbd>[**updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/SirDerpington/zSzks/8/)</kbd>

```
$(".sort").sortable({
    //other config
    update: function (event, ui) {
        $('.sort > tr .counter').each(function (index) {
            $(this).text(index + 1);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The table rows are populated by iterating over a collection of objects (I'm using jsp el and java) in a foreach loop, counter is actually something like  <c:set var="counter" value="0" /> ; increment by 1 in the loop, I need the counter and position in the same row. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Sorry just to clarify: I'm attempting to overwrite the value of position with the value of counter and have an idea how to do it as long as I don't have to split tables. I was wondering if that's doable in sortable. I that's  not possible then I'd have to think about a different approach.

Comment: You could correct the counter value if a row was moved. See my updated fiddle.

Comment: Cool...was not sure if that would help you but it seems so. Always glad to help! :)

Comment: yeah thanks a lot, I spent good 2h trying to find a solution to this problem. I have an idea how to implement the rest of the stuff I need as long as I'm dealing with one table.